# numpy replace array elements with average of 2*2 blocks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an `m*n matrix` in `numpy`. I want to divide my matrix into 2*2 blocks and then replace each element with average of the elements in its block. for example consider the following array:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
```

I want to produce this matrix:

```
[
    [3.5, 3.5, 5.5, 5.5]
    [3.5, 3.5, 5.5, 5.5]
    [11.5, 11.5, 13.5, 13.5]
    [11.5, 11.5, 13.5, 13.5]
]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Should I use for loops?

Comment: Finally posed the way I've been looking for! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to reshape splitting each of those two axes into two more and find `mean` along the latter of those two, giving us the average values. We will keep the dimensions with `keepdims=True`, so as to facilitate replicating along the reduced axes later on with `np.repeat` for the final output.

Thus, one implementation would be -

```
b = a.reshape(2,2,2,2).mean((1,3), keepdims=1)
out = np.repeat(np.repeat(b,(2),axis=(1)),(2), axis=3).reshape(4,4)
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])

In [18]: b = a.reshape(2,2,2,2).mean((1,3), keepdims=1)

In [19]: np.repeat(np.repeat(b,(2),axis=(1)),(2), axis=3).reshape(4,4)
Out[19]: 
array([[  3.5,   3.5,   5.5,   5.5],
       [  3.5,   3.5,   5.5,   5.5],
       [ 11.5,  11.5,  13.5,  13.5],
       [ 11.5,  11.5,  13.5,  13.5]])
```

Generically put, the solution would look like this -

```
m,n = a.shape
p,q = (2,2) # Block size
b = a.reshape(m//p,p,n//q,q).mean((1,3), keepdims=1)
out = np.repeat(np.repeat(b,(p),axis=(1)),(q), axis=3).reshape(a.shape)
```

**Performance boost**

We could replace that replicating part with an initialization based section, like so -

```
out = np.empty((m//p,p,n//q,q),dtype=float)
out[:] = b
out.shape = a.shape
```

Comment: who are you @Divakar amazing answer as always.

Comment: I get a reshape error at the first reshape: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 72768 into shape (96,2,189,2)`. Is this because the blocks don't go?